Ball with 3 openings meeting at the centre.
Assume we drill 3 holes on the surface of a solid ball until they meet simultaneously at the centre.
I saw a drawing proof claiming that this ball with three openings can be stretched so that it becomes a donut with 2 holes.
But the drawing is confusing rather than illuminating and plus I am skeptical of it's validity. Is this really what we get?

This animated diagram by Greg Egan may help: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/mathematical/KleinDualInsideOut.gif It's from https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/04/polygonal_decompositions_of_su.html It's a 3 hole torus made by drilling 4 holes into a sphere, so it's related to your construction.

Drill one hole until you reach the center. The resulting shape still has genus $0$ since you've made an indentation rather than a hole. Now drill the other two holes.
